# How do I prevent Visual Studio from opening files in read only mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

For some reason Visual Studio 2019 sometimes (not always) opens files in read only mode. The file itself is not marked as read only in the file system, it's only in VS. When I close it and open it again, it's suddenly in normal mode.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks, when a file is locked:

[image]

That's very annoying.
How can I disable this "feature"?

Comment: Add screenshot of your issue this will help to understand

Comment: It is normal while debugging with Edit+Continue support turned on and the debugger not in a break state.  Context is important.

Comment: @NishitZinzuvadiya I just added a screenshot.

Comment: @HansPassant I wouldn't be surprised, if it happend during debugging, but I encounter it during normal coding. I cannot really pin it down to a certain function, feature or process. It just happens.

Comment: @Ash your screenshot indicates you're debugging.  If you can reproduce this when you're not debugging, then you should send feedback to the VS team as that seems like a bug.